# How i can calculate days between two dates

Tags: powerbuilder

I want write code in PowerBuilder11.5 to calculate the number of days In which the balance remain as it is until the process of withdrawal or deposit.

Calculate Days between 1/1/2016 to 1/6/2016 and display the results in data window.

```
------------------
Table of processes
Acc_no /date/transaction/amount/balance
------------------
(1)(25/1/2016)(debit)(500)(1500)
---------
(1)(16/2/2016)(credit)(700)(2200)
---------
(1)(5/5/2016)(debit)(1500)(700)
```

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DaysAfter` function. From documentation:

> **Description**
>
> Gets the number of days one date occurs after another.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> DaysAfter ( date1, date2 )
>
> **Return value**
>
> Long. Returns a long containing the number of days date2 occurs after
>   date1. If date2 occurs before date1, DaysAfter returns a negative
>   number.